# Какой язык выбрать для мобильной разработки?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Собираюсь начать, но мучает вопрос какой язык выбрать - kotlin либо java?
Вроде java уже испытанный и хорошо подходит, НО google начал продвигать kotlin и назвал его главным языком для разработки мобильных приложений .

Comment: Сложный вопрос. С одной стороны Котлин гораздо удобнее Явы. С другой он сложнее в освоении, если нет опыта с Явой. По крайней мере многие моменты в нём понятнее, если известна Ява. Возможно стоит начать с неё, а потом уже переходить на Котлин. Переход будет довольно простым потом.

Comment: Я как и ЮрийСПб советую начать с Java, (сейчас большинство вакансий требует именно уверенные знания Java, опыт работы с Kotlin обычно описывается в "плюсах")

Comment: Java или Kotlin это всего лишь инструменты. Гораздо важнее изучать платформу и решения для нее. Зная Kotlin очень легко освоить Swift, но это не значит что вы уже и iOS developer, саму платформу грызть и грызть надо.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ прост. В наше время жить зная Java, но не зная Kotlin очень просто. Жить зная kotlin, но не зная Java - куда сложнее. Все же родные адроидовские классы и подавляющее большинство библиотек и примеров написаны на Java, и копаться в них рано или поздно придется. Плюс чтобы писать на Kotlin "правильно" крайне полезно просматривать генерируемый байт-код или декомпелированный java-код. Ну и в конце концов Java много где применима, а kotlin пока кроме андроида особой популярностью не пользуется

Вердикт - начинайте с Java. На Kotlin потом пересесть будет легко и ооочень приятно

Answer (score 0):

В принципе предыдущий ответ верен, но не до конца: сейчас появилась такая тенденция у которых Kotlin стоит первым языком и это не спроста. Дело в том что Kotlin пришел ему на замену и отлично с этим справляется. Многие компании уже хотят видеть именно Kotlin, а где нужна Java вы уже туда всё-равно не попадаете (минимум пол года на изучение) к тому моменту все мелкие и средние компании перейдут на Kotlin как и заказчики, уже требуют Kotlin. А Java, останется для поддержки старых проектов и библиотек (мне самому не нравилась эта тенденция, но изучил и работаю с Kotlin).

По поводу того что Kotlin легче даётся тем кто знает Java утверждение верно только если вы уже хорошо знаете Java, а к этому моменту уже может как такового и Android-a не существовать.

Библиотеки на Java вы начнете понимать по ходу изучения Kotlin, ведь Kotlin по сути своей это надстройка над Java, а что будет неясно, можно открыть и почитать. Кстати сейчас библиотеки начинают также писать на Kotlin-e.

Вывод: решать вам что лучше.
Если Java то рекомендую начать с книг "Философия Java" или более для продвинутых "Java в действии".
Если Kotlin то "Kotlin в действии" - после прочтения и по ходу работы/изучения языка желательно будет подчитывать на ночь "Философия Java" избежите множества проблем с которыми столкнулся я. Я читал другие книги но они были очень сложны для новичка или бесполезны.

P.S. Обязательно проделывайте все пример которые вам даются, даже если вам кажется что вы понимаете как это делается или вы что-то подобное делали. Потом и найти кусок кода легче и подглянуть есть куда.

P.S.S. Ну и на последок, Android вещь специфическая и своеобразная, после изучения книги советую Уроки на Startandroid или подчитывать оригинальную документацию для Android. Например начните с жизненного цикла Activity и Fragmenta.